# Как убрать наложение элементов друг на друга при первом заходе на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я сделал две полупрозрачные "кнопки", появляющиеся слева страницы на одном и том же месте.

- Кнопка А появляется, когда пользователь чуть прокрутил ползунок (чтобы нажав на нее, пользователь мог вернуться на верх страницы).
- Кнопка Б появляется в самом верху страницы вместо кнопки А, чтобы вернуться на предыдущую страницу.

Они исправно работают, если пользователь прокрутил ползунок хоть чуть-чуть. Но при первом заходе на страницу они появляются друг поверх друга. Как желательно с помощью jquery сделать так, чтобы при первом заходе на страницу два этих блока не появлялись друг поверх друга?

```js
$(function(){
var hide =  window.scroll(0, 1);
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: hide }, 1);

$("#scrolltothetopExtra").bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);    
});
$("#scrolltothetop").bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);    
});
$("#scrolltothetop").hover(function () {
 $(this).animate({
  backgroundColor : '#8A8A8A',
 }, 200);
    }, function () {
 $(this).animate({
  backgroundColor : '',
 }, 200);
});
$("#scrolltothetopExtra").hover(function () {
 $("#scrolltothetop").animate({
  backgroundColor : '#8A8A8A',
 }, 200);
    }, function () {
 $("#scrolltothetop").animate({
  backgroundColor : '',
 }, 200);
});
$("#goback").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor : '#8A8A8A',
    }, 200);
    }, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor : '',
    }, 200);
});
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    var y = window.scrollY
    if (y == 0) {
        $('#scrolltothetopExtra').css({
            'display' : 'none',
        });
        $('#scrolltothetop').css({
            'display' : 'none',
        });
        $('#goback').css({
            'display' : 'block',
        });
    } else {
        $('#scrolltothetopExtra').css({
            'display' : 'block',
        });
        $('#scrolltothetop').css({
            'display' : 'block',
        });
        $('#goback').css({
            'display' : 'none',
        });

    }
});
});
```

```html
<!-- для того чтобы был скролл -->
<div style='height:2000px;width:1px;background:white;'></div>
<!-- это код для кнопки наверх -->
<div style="display: block;width: 170px;height: 100%;opacity: 0.3;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;z-index: 10;cursor: pointer;" id='scrolltothetop'>
<div style="display: block;width: 1px;height: 35px;"></div>
<div style="margin-left: 35px;">
 <img src="../img/up.png">
 <b style="z-index: 2;font-family: Arial;font-size: 20px;">Наверх</b>
</div>
</div>
<div id="scrolltothetopExtra" style="display: block;height: 100%;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;z-index: 1000;cursor: pointer;"></div>

<!-- это для кнопки на предыд страницу -->
<div onclick="javascript:history.back();return false;" style="display: block;width: 170px;height: 100%;opacity: 0.3;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;cursor: pointer;" id="goback">
<div style="display: block;width: 1px;height: 35px;"></div>
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
 <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <img style="transform: rotate(-90deg);" src="../img/up.png">
  <img style="transform: rotate(-90deg);" src="../img/up.png">
  <img style="transform: rotate(-90deg);" src="../img/up.png">
 </div>
 <br>
 <b style="z-index: 2;font-family: Arial;font-size: 20px;margin-left: 50px;">На</b>
 <b style="z-index: 2;font-family: Arial;font-size: 20px;">предыдущую</b>
 <b style="z-index: 2;font-family: Arial;font-size: 20px;margin-left: 20px;">страницу</b>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно какой-нибудь код увидеть? Кнопок, скрипта, который отвечает за скрытие

Comment: Если вы задаете вопрос связанный с программированием, ,будьте добры и приложите код, вы бы сами смогли ответить на подобный вопрос, не посмотрев при этом код?

Comment: @ThisMan поправил вопрос. Здесь он при прокрутке все равно продолжает накладываться почему-то. На деле такого нет. Вопрос все тот-же, чтобы не накладывались сверху при первом заходе на страницу

Comment: @Vearo поправил вопрос. Здесь он при прокрутке все равно продолжает накладываться почему-то. На деле такого нет. Вопрос все тот-же, чтобы не накладывались сверху при первом заходе на страницу

Comment: Вы приводите код в вопросе, который не соответствует вопросую Как мы можем помочь в такой ситуации? Никак!